# Iterating over features in Google Earth Engine

Tags: javascript, google-earth-engine, time-series, iteration

I am using the Zonal Time Series plotter from the LandTrendr scripts to plot an NDVI time series for a geometry.  I would like to modify the script to be able to loop through objects in a table, because I ultimately have 1000+ areas that I would like to create a time series plot for.  I have seen the GEE documentation for [iterating over a feature collection](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/feature_collection_mapping), but I'm having a hard time applying it to my script.

[This is the script](https://code.earthengine.google.com/e1568cafc60506bcb27e089bdbe755ae) that successfully plots a time series for a single geometry.  How can I modify this script to loop through objects in a table to generate time series for many geometries?